# Somando Positivos no Intervalo

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa em Linguagem C, mas o site informa que a saída do programa não é aceita.

[Somando Positivos no Intervalo](https://www.thehuxley.com/problem/406)

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num1, num2, i, soma=0, temp;
    scanf("%i", &num1);
    scanf("%i", &num2);

    if (num1 > num2) {
        temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }

    for ( i = num1 ; i < num2+1; i++ ) {
        if (i>=0) {
            soma = soma + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%i", soma);

    return 0;
}
```

Print dos erros: [Duas imagens do erro que está sendo exibido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GBMG.jpg)

Comment: O que é que lhe dá erro concretamente? é que eu testei num programa e funciona.

Comment: Um à parte, se pretende somar esses 2 números, é mais fácil fazer apenas `soma= num1 + num2;` e assim não precisa de nenhum ciclo for

Comment: Oi, você poderia ver os screenshots, foi mostrado que o programa não passou em 2 casos e não sei como resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão pede que seja somado cada número positivo dentro do intervalo, então dentro do ciclo você deve fazer:

```
for (i = num1 ; i < num2+1; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        soma = soma + i;
    }
}
```

Se por exemplo o intervalo for 5 10, seu código está fazendo 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1, quando deveria ser 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10.